# How to calculate correlation between 1D numpy array and every column of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, correlation, numpy-ndarray

I have a 1D numpy array (y) and 2D numpy array (x) and I calculate correlation between y and every column in x as below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)

x = rng.random((3, 3))
y = rng.random(3)

for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    print( pearsonr(x[:, i], y)[0]  )
```

I was wondering how I can get the correlation values without `For` loop. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose these approaches, all of which lead to the same result as your proposed solution:

- Approach 1: A solution similar to the one proposed by [Lucas M. Uriarte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73658812/9302488), using [numpy.corrcoef](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html):

  ```
  np.corrcoef(y,x.T)[0][1:]
  ```
- Approach 2: The function for calculating the correlation is rewritten using numpy functions:

  ```
  def corr_np(data1, data2):
      mean1 = data1.mean() 
      mean2 = data2.mean()
      std1 = data1.std()
      std2 = data2.std()
      corr = ((data1*data2).mean()-mean1*mean2)/(std1*std2)
      return corr

  def paerson_np(x, y):
      return np.array([corr_np(x[:, i], y) for i in range(x.shape[1])])
  ```
- Approach 3: The function for calculating the correlation is rewritten, using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up the calculations:

  ```
  @nb.njit()
  def corr_nb(data1, data2):
      M = data1.size
      sum1 = 0.
      sum2 = 0.
      for i in range(M):
          sum1 += data1[i]
          sum2 += data2[i]
      mean1 = sum1 / M
      mean2 = sum2 / M

      var_sum1 = 0.
      var_sum2 = 0.
      cross_sum = 0.
      for i in range(M):
          var_sum1 += (data1[i] - mean1) ** 2
          var_sum2 += (data2[i] - mean2) ** 2
          cross_sum += (data1[i] * data2[i])

     std1 = (var_sum1 / M) ** .5
     std2 = (var_sum2 / M) ** .5
     cross_mean = cross_sum / M

     return (cross_mean - mean1 * mean2) / (std1 * std2)

  @nb.njit()
  def paerson_nb(x, y):
      return np.array([corr_nb(x[:, i], y) for i in range(x.shape[1])])
  ```

**Execution time comparison**

I experimented to see which solution was more efficient, comparing the 3 approaches I listed above and your solution (which I will call approach 0). The instances for the experiments have the following structure:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
n = 20000
x = rng.random((n, n))
y = rng.random(n)
```

Results:

- Approch 0 (your solution):

  ```
  %timeit approach0(x, y) :-> 15.6 s ± 200 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Approach 1:

  ```
  %timeit np.corrcoef(y,x.T)[0][1:] :-> 37.4 s ± 3.68 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Approach 2:

  ```
  %timeit paerson_np(x, y) :-> 19.1 s ± 351 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Approach 3:

  ```
  %timeit paerson_nb(x, y) :-> 7.81 s ± 56.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```

The solution with numba(approch 3), is about 2 times faster than your solution(approach 0) and the solution with numpy(approach 2). The solution with numpy.corrcoef is clearly the slowest: about 2 times slower than aprroaches 0 and 2, and even more than 5 times slower than the solution with numba.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a numpy native solution without for loops:

```py
def vector_corr_np(data1, data2):
    data1 = np.atleast_2d(data1)
    data2 = np.atleast_2d(data2)
    mean1 = data1.mean(axis=1) 
    mean2 = data2.mean(axis=1)
    std1 = data1.std(axis=1)
    std2 = data2.std(axis=1)
    corr = ((data1*data2).mean(axis=1)-mean1*mean2)/(std1*std2)
    return corr
```

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
n = 20000
x = rng.random((n, n))
y = rng.random(n)
%timeit vector_corr_np(x, y)
5.46 s ± 32.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```