Most efficient way of running correlation of a small sequence against another larger sequence to try to find matching index
In Python, I want to take a smaller sequence of numbers, and find the area along a very large sequence of numbers that has the highest correlation to this smaller sequence of numbers.
Is there an efficient way to do this besides brute force ie. taking a subset of the larger sequence of the same length as the smaller sequences, calculating the coefficient, then incrementing the starting index, and doing this over and over again?
Is there some functionality that numpy or some other math package that can do this efficiently?

This might be useful: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html#scipy.signal.correlate

I'd suggest to use numpy for the task, e.g:
import numba

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/73663164/10035985
@numba.njit
def corr_nb(data1, data2):
    mean1 = data1.mean()
    mean2 = data2.mean()
    std1 = data1.std()
    std2 = data2.std()
    corr = ((data1 * data2).mean() - mean1 * mean2) / (std1 * std2)
    return corr


@numba.njit
def find_corr(small, big):
    n = len(small)

    curr_max_corr = -np.inf
    curr_max_index = -1

    for i in range(0, len(big) - n):
        c = corr_nb(small, big[i : i + n])
        if c > curr_max_corr:
            curr_max_corr = c
            curr_max_index = i

    return curr_max_index


Benchmark for small array of 7 elements and big array of 500_000 elements:
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

big_arr = np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=500_000, dtype="int8")

# some small_arr that we try to correlate:
small_arr = np.array([1, -1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6], dtype="int8")


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/73663164/10035985
@numba.njit
def corr_nb(data1, data2):
    mean1 = data1.mean()
    mean2 = data2.mean()
    std1 = data1.std()
    std2 = data2.std()
    corr = ((data1 * data2).mean() - mean1 * mean2) / (std1 * std2)
    return corr


@numba.njit
def find_corr(small, big):
    n = len(small)

    curr_max_corr = -np.inf
    curr_max_index = -1

    for i in range(0, len(big) - n):
        c = corr_nb(small, big[i : i + n])
        if c > curr_max_corr:
            curr_max_corr = c
            curr_max_index = i

    return curr_max_index


i = find_corr(small_arr, big_arr)
print("Index:", i)
print("Small:", small_arr)
print("Big:  ", big_arr[i : i + len(small_arr)])

t = timeit("find_corr(small_arr, big_arr)", number=1, globals=globals())
print(t)

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):
Index: 74716
Small: [ 1 -1  2  3  4 -5  6]
Big:   [ 1 -3  2  3  3 -7  7]
0.041199692990630865


Good answer. When both arrays are large one could possibly speed up calculations by computing the correlation coefficient for big array elements i, i+1, ... j from those for i-1,i,...,j-1. By way of example variance for elements i-1,i,...,j-1 depend on SS = Σ(k = i-1 to j-1)x(k)^2 and S = Σ(k = i-1 to j-1)x(k), so the sum of squares for k = i to j = SS + x(j)^2 - x(i-2)^2 and similar for updating S. Messy for updating the correlation coefficient, however.
